# Python+SeleniumWebDriver date selection problem pychram

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem for one of the automatic tests I would like the test to substitute a specific date from the calendar but unfortunately the date does not substitute, please help how to solve this case ?

```
class MvNowy(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_mv_nowy(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
    # 1.Wchodzę na stronę orange.pl
        driver.get("https://www.orange.pl/")
        print('Wszedłem na stronę główną orange')
    # 12.Wypełnianie danych klienta
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "firstName").send_keys('TESTABCD')
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "lastName").send_keys('TESTOABCD')
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "pesel").send_keys('14030356439')
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "idNumber").send_keys('AKH467112')
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
        elem = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"undefined-identificationRegisterDate-undefined")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value ='2022-10-05';",elem)
        elem.send_keys("2022-10-05")
        driver.find_element(By.NAME, "postalCode").send_keys('05-270')
        print('Uzupełniliśmy dane klienta')
```

[FOTO CODE CALENDAR HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl5QT.png)